# multiple definitions for the operation. Please rename or remove all operations with the duplicated name before continuing

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I am using Apollo Codegen CLI to generate types for the graphql queries. However running into the issue mentioned. For now I have generated the schema file and trying to generate types for same. I tried to remove the mentioned query from the schema, it still is showing the same error. Is there any way to skip these queries like any optional parameter ? Any work around suggested is welcomed.

Error :   Generating query files
›   Error: Error initializing Apollo GraphQL project "Unnamed Project": Error: Error in "Loading queries for Unnamed Project": Error: ️️There are
›   multiple definitions for the `xyz` operation. Please rename or remove all operations with the duplicated name before continuing.
error Command failed with exit code 2.

Comment: Any solution on this?

Comment: @tjadli worked for me, I renamed all the queries which had matching names. Although i did not find any solution to skip those